# Exposure compensation in “manual” mode and auto ISO?

Tags: canon, manual-mode, exposure-compensation, auto-iso

Canon 7D Mk II: Is there a way to adjust exposure compensation when I’m using auto iso in “manual” mode? In other words, I’m not using “full manual,” but rather what might be considered “iso priority.” I want to set my shutter speed, set my aperture, and then have the camera vary the iso based on the amount of compensated exposure I choose.

I’ve been digging through the custom settings, and I’m coming up short. I can switch into Av or Tv, adjust exposure compensation, then switch back to manual-with-auto-iso, and the bottom exposure meter will indicate compensation. However, the right side exposure meter (the one we use for manual mode) indicates no exposure compensation. Capturing an image reveals that there’s no compensation being applied (as indicated by the histogram).

Comment: It seems like the premise of your question is wrong. X priority means you set X and the camera sets the rest. ISO priority means you’d set the ISO, instead of leaving the ISO on auto.

Comment: The bottom scale is *never* an exposure meter with the 7D Mark II. It *always* shows the current exposure compensation setting.

Comment: For more, please see [What's the difference between “exposure level indicator” and “exposure setting meter” in the Canon EOS 1DX Mark II viewfinder?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/75876/15871) The 7D Mark II and 1D X Mark II are pretty much identical in this regard.

Comment: Are you saying entering an EC value of +3 and taking a photo and then entering an EC value of -3 and taking a photo of the exact same scene using the same Tv and Av does not result in two different ISO values being selected? Are you on one end or the other of the camera's ISO range (or the selected *Manually Settable ISO Speed Range* or *ISO Speed range for 'Auto IS'* chosen under the [Shooting 2 (2nd red tab)→ISO Speed Settings→ISO Speed Range/Auto ISO Range] menu?

Comment: Not sure if this is too old now. But did you find a way to do this. I want to do the same on my eos r. I can set exp in Av/Tv and it will stay set when I switch to M mode. But I was wondering if there is any way to do it from M mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is now possible to use Exposure Compensation in Manual mode with Auto ISO with some of Canon’s newer cameras:

EOS-1D X

EOS-1DX Mark II

EOS 5DS / EOS 5DS R

EOS 7D Mark II

EOS 80D

The easiest way is to assign a Custom Function to the “Set” button.

[Brian Worley: Manual mode, auto ISO and exposure compensation](https://www.p4pictures.com/2016/08/manual-mode-auto-iso-exposure-compensation/)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Exposure compensation does not change your resulting exposure result? Have you tried it, or are you just looking at the numbers?

Auto ISO Cannot change your manual setting numbers, but it should change the goal of the Auto ISO, changing ISO, and resulting in a different compensated exposure of the picture result.   Assuming the settings in in reach of the ISO.