# What is the maximum amount of exposure bracketing the a7R II can do?

Tags: sony, sony-alpha

The [user manual](http://download.sony-asia.com/consumer/IM/4576983111.pdf) of the Sony a7R II does not seem to specify this detail. I have heard different things from various reviews (maybe it changed in a firmware update?) so I'm not sure what to believe.

On a related note, some cameras like the [Canon 5D mark 3 and 5DS](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/75813/34510) can be pushed to 7 brackets spaced by 3 EVs using the custom function menu (for a total of 18 stops of dynamic range, from 1/8000 to 30"), and can shift the ISO as well as the shutter speed to prevent extremely long exposures (e.g. 1/8000 at ISO 100 to 4" at ISO 800). Does the a7R2 have a similar capability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cursory Google brings up several solid results, including [this one](http://briansmith.com/ten-great-new-settings-on-sony-a7rii/), which reports 9 shot bracketing:

> Sony a7RII features more bracketing mode options than any other a7-Series camera, including NINE-SHOT bracketing, available in both Continuous and Single Bracketing modes
>
> 3-image: 0.3 EV, 0.5 EV, 0.7 EV, 1.0 EV, 2.0 EV, 3.0 EV
>
> 5-image: 0.3 EV, 0.5 EV, 0.7 EV, 1.0 EV, 2.0 EV, 3.0 EV
>
> 9-image: 0.3 EV, 0.5 EV, 0.7 EV, 1.0 EV

He has screen shots of the settings so it would seem to be a fairly reliable source.